# What's the difference between 「殺人者」「殺戮者」 and 「大量殺人者」?

Tags: grammar, words, word-usage

Is it a matter of the degree of the crime like "**satsurikusha**" is worse than "**satsujinsha**" and "**tairyousatsujinsha**" is worse than "**satsurikusha**"? Or are "**satsurikusha**" and "**tairyousatsujinsha**" on the "same" level?

Comment: https://hinative.com/ja/questions/17064661

Answer (score 2):

- 殺人 is a relatively objective word for "killing" or "murder".
- 大量殺人 is just "mass murder", as the kanji suggest. The means of killing is not important. It's still a relatively objective term, and Wikipedia articles may prefer this.
- 殺戮 refers to brutal and cruel mass murders, typically using rifles, chainsaws, poison gas, etc. Tabloids and novel authors may prefer a sensational word like this.